# How to move a 2d sprite to a target location while avoiding obstacles?

Tags: android, java, collision-detection, sprites, input

How can I get a 2d sprite to move to a position clicked on the screen, without bumping into other objects? I'm programming in java using the android API library

I have created a surface view and loaded my sprites as a bitmap object.

Comment: You might try doing an internet search on this topic before asking questions here.

Comment: @JonathanDickinson I think this is a valid question for gamedev. The question is about finding a way from A to B without bumping into other obstacles (if I understood correctly).

Comment: @bummzack in which case it's a duplicate.

Comment: @JonathanDickinson feel free to mark it as such then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on your game. If you have a dense environment with restricted moving paths (eg. something like a maze), then you should look into [path-finding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinding). If you have only few and spaced obstacles which may even be moving, then look into [steering-behaviors](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/steer/), especially [obstacle-avoidance](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/steer/Obstacle.html).

**Update:** While path-finding usually works with a starting location and a target-location (eg. your sprites current position and the position you clicked), this might not be so obvious with steering-behaviors. In the case of steering-behaviors, you can use a combination of behaviors. Eg. start with a behavior like "[Arrival](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/steer/Arrival.html)" where the target is where you last clicked. During this behavior, check for obstacles in the way and switch to the *obstacle-avoidance* behavior if you detect an obstacle in your path. As soon as the way is clear, re-apply the *arrival* behavior. Alternatively you could also implement your own behavior that takes everything into account.

Comment: Thanks for the information this definitely gives me much to think about and a bit of testing to do.